# remove views/controllers from UIScrollView/PageControl at run time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm using a scrollview and a pagecontrol to render several images, very similar to the built-in photo app. I'm using this code to setup the controllers when the view loads:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < [photos count]; i++) {
    [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
self.viewControllers = controllers;
[controllers release];

scrollArea.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollArea.contentSize = CGSizeMake(newW * [photos count], newH);
scrollArea.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollArea.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollArea.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollArea.delegate = self;

pageControl.numberOfPages = [photos count];
```

newW and newH are just two variables I'm using to keep track of the size when the orientation changes.
My loadScrollViewWithPage method:

```
- (void) loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= [photos count]) return;

    PhotoViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];

    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        controller = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];
        controller.imgPath = (NSString *)[photos objectAtIndex:page];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {

        CGRect frame = scrollArea.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollArea addSubview:controller.view];        
    }
}
```

And here is my issue. I need to unload controllers/views when I need it. I thought I could use something like this:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < [photos count]; i++) {
    [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

I want to do it, so load completely new views into the scrollview.

I also tried something liek this with no luck:

```
for(UIView *subview in [self.scrollArea subviews]) {
 [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to make sure the subviews of `scrollView` stay in sync with the items in `self.viewControllers` as you update the latter? The easiest thing is to do something like this whenever you replace one of the items:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
if ((NSNull *)vc != [NSNull null] && [vc isViewLoaded]) [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:foo];
```